# Calculate random effect predictions manually for a linear mixed model

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am trying to calculate the random effect predictions from a linear mixed model by hand, and
using notation provided by Wood in *Generalized Additive Models: an introduction with R* (pg 294 / pg 307 of pdf), 
I am getting confused over what each parameters represents.

Below is a summary from Wood.

Define a linear mixed model

$$ Y = X\beta + Zb + \epsilon $$

where b  $\sim$ N(0, $\psi$), and $\epsilon \sim$ N(0, $\sigma^{2}$)

If b and y are random variables with joint normal distribution

\begin{align*}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    b\\
    y
  \end{bmatrix} &\sim  N
\begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0\\
    X\beta
  \end{bmatrix}\!\!,&
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \psi   & \Sigma_{by} \\
    \Sigma_{yb}& \Sigma_{\theta}\sigma^{2} 
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}\\
 \end{align*}

The RE predictions are calculated by

\begin{align*}
E[b \mid y] &= \Sigma_{by} \Sigma_{yy}^{-1} (y - x\beta)\\ 
            &= \Sigma_{by}\Sigma_{\theta}^{-1}(y - x \beta) / \sigma^{2}\\
            &= \psi z^{T}\Sigma_{\theta}^{-1} (y - x \beta) / \sigma^{2}
\end{align*}

where $\Sigma_{\theta} = Z\psi Z^{T} /\sigma^{2} + I_{n}$

Using an random intercept model example from `lme4` R package I get output

```
library(lme4)
m = lmer(angle ~ temp + (1 | replicate), data=cake)
summary(m)

% Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
% Formula: angle ~ temp + (1 | replicate)
%    Data: cake
% 
% REML criterion at convergence: 1671.7
% 
% Scaled residuals: 
%      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
% -2.83605 -0.56741 -0.02306  0.54519  2.95841 
% 
% Random effects:
%  Groups    Name        Variance Std.Dev.
%  replicate (Intercept) 39.19    6.260   
%  Residual              23.51    4.849   
% Number of obs: 270, groups:  replicate, 15
% 
% Fixed effects:
%             Estimate Std. Error t value
% (Intercept)  0.51587    3.82650   0.135
% temp         0.15803    0.01728   9.146
% 
% Correlation of Fixed Effects:
%      (Intr)
% temp -0.903
```

So from this, I think $\psi$ = 23.51, $(y-X\beta)$ can be estimated from `cake$angle - predict(m, re.form=NA)`, 
and `sigma` from the square of the population level residuals.

```
th = 23.51
zt = getME(m, "Zt") 
res = cake$angle - predict(m, re.form=NA)
sig = sum(res^2) / (length(res)-1)
```

Multiplying these together gives

```
th * zt %*% res / sig
         [,1]
1  103.524878
2   94.532914
3   33.934892
4    8.131864
---
```

which is not correct when compared to

```
> ranef(m)
$replicate
   (Intercept)
1   14.2365633
2   13.0000038
3    4.6666680
4    1.1182799
---
```

Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two problems (I confess it took me like 40 minutes to spot the second one):

1. You must not compute $\sigma^2$ with the square of residuals, it is estimated by REML as `23.51`, and there is no guarantee that the BLUPs will have the same variance.

   ```
   sig <- 23.51
   ```

   And this is not $\psi$ ! Which is estimated as `39.19`

   ```
   psi <- 39.19
   ```
2. The residuals are not obtained with `cake$angle - predict(m, re.form=NA)` but with `residuals(m)`.

Putting it together:

```
> psi/sig * zt %*% residuals(m)
15 x 1 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"
         [,1]
1  14.2388572
2  13.0020985
3   4.6674200
4   1.1184601
5   0.2581062
6  -3.2908537
7  -4.6351567
8  -4.5813846
9  -4.6351567
10 -3.1833095
11 -2.1616392
12 -1.1399689
13 -0.2258429
14 -4.0974355
15 -5.3341942
```

which is similar to `ranef(m)`.

I really don't get what `predict` computes.

---

PS. To answer your last remark, the point is that we use the "residuals" $\hat\epsilon$ as a way to obtain the vector $PY$ where $P = V^{-1} -  V^{-1}  X \left(X' V^{-1} X\right)^{-1} X' V^{-1}$. This matrix is computed during the REML algorithm. It is related to the BLUPs of random terms by
$$ \hat\epsilon = \sigma^2 PY $$
and
$$ \hat b = \psi Z^t PY. $$

Thus $ \hat b = \psi / \sigma^2 Z^t \hat\epsilon $.

Comment: Thanks Elvis. I am struggling a wee bit to align the values you have used back to the equations above, however, it seems there are many ways to skin a cat. The residuals I find a bit surprising as I thought it is meant to be $y-x\beta$, (fixed effect) whereas residuals is calculated using the random effects. (see the difference between `plot(residuals(m), cake$angle-predict(m, re.form=NULL)) ; plot(residuals(m), cake$angle-predict(m, re.form=NA))`).

Comment: A way using the fixed effect, and the third version of the E[b|y] above: 
`z = getME(m, "Z")  ; big_sig = solve(((z * psi) %*% zt ) / sig + diag(270)) ; 
psi/sig * zt %*% big_sig %*% (cake$angle-predict(m, re.form=NA))`. Thanks for pointing out the correct items.

Comment: One final Q if I may, can I get either of $\Sigma_{by}$ or  $\Sigma_{yy}$ directly from the output?

Comment: Isn’t $\Sigma_{yb}$ equal to $\psi Z$ ?

Comment: Elvis, I had another wee think on this (I know I'm slow). I think using the residuals like this isn't really sensible as it uses the predicted values (and so residuals) at the RE level to calculate, so we are using it at both sides of your equation. (so it uses the RE predictions (E[b|y]) to make the predictions of residuals even though these are the terms we are trying to predict))

Comment: @user2957945 I added a PS to explain why it is legit to do so. I hope you will be convinced.

Comment: Thanks very much again for your works Elvis, greatly appreciated. I'll go  and try to understand. cheers

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but I don't see how this answer works for more than two random effects -- if the dimension of $\psi$ is $2\times 2$, then it isn't conformable with $Z^T$.

Comment: $\psi$ is a scalar, the variance of $b$ is $\psi I_q$ where $q$ is the dimension of $b$. Look at the R code in the answer, it should be helpful.

Comment: Right, in the example here there is only one random intercept.  But if you had more than one random term then $\psi$ wouldn't be a scalar.  But since posting this comment, I've figured out that $\psi$ in the general case is block diagonal, with each block being the covariance matrix of the random effects.

Comment: $\psi$ is a scalar, period.

Comment: If that is true, then I am confused.  What happens in a model with more than one random effect, and correlated random effects in particular?

Comment: Or, more precisely, it isn't $\psi$, the covariance of the random effects that gets multiplied by $Z^T$, but rather a block-diagonal matrix with $\psi$ making up the blocks... Unless I'm wrong -- these models are complicated and poorly documented.

Comment: In that case, you would for example put $var(b) = \psi K$.